How to specify SELECT'ed field in WHERE clause of query when the field has the same alias as column name
SQLite, unlike most DBMS's, allows you to put expressions in the WHERE clause that are fields declared in the select statement that aren't strictly columns.
For example,
SELECT "T"."Id" + 1 AS "NewId" FROM "MyTable" AS "T" WHERE "NewId" = 1;

SQLite allows you to give these selected columns the same name as an existing column in your table, but existing columns seem to take precedence over the selected columns. To illustrate this, say "MyTable" has a single row with "Id" = 1. The following query
SELECT "T"."Id" + 1 AS "Id" FROM "MyTable" AS "T" WHERE "Id" = 1;

Returns 1 record (2), so it's clear SQLite is evaluating the expression "Id" in the WHERE clause as "MyTable"."Id".
Is there any way to qualify the "Id" expression in the WHERE clause to be the selected one?
I understand that I can just name it something unique like "NewId" to accomplish this.
I want to know if there is any syntax that allows me to specify an identifier expression as "I want the value from the SELECT clause, NOT what my table column is called".

You can use a subquery here to work around the fact that the projection clause can't be named within the same query (the resulting columns have no name they are bound to):
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT "MyTable"."Id" + 1 AS "Id"
      FROM "MyTable"
     ) AS "T"
WHERE "T"."Id" = 1;

